# write() socket programming keeps program from advancing

Tags: c++, sockets, client

Hi I have a simple problem I think, but I am not able to figure it out. Here is my code snippet

```
void makefilerequest(){
  int n;
  char buffer[256];
  char file[] = "test.txt";

  printf("Enter file: ");
  bzero(file, 256);
  //fgets(buffer, 255, stdin);
  n = write(sockfd, file, strlen(file));
  if( n < 0)
    error("ERROR writing to socket");

  bzero(buffer,256);
  n = read(sockfd,buffer,255);
  if (n < 0) 
    error("ERROR reading from socket");
  printf("%s\n",buffer);
}
```

My problem is when I try to set a char[] that contains the info to write to the socket my program does not move forward it stops at `n = write(sockfd, file, strlen(file));`. However when I read in say `test.txt` from stdin it works and my program executes. If I make the following changes it works but I don't want to pass it the information through stdin.

```
void makefilerequest(){
  int n;
  char buffer[256];
  char file[] = "test.txt";

  printf("Enter file: ");
  bzero(buffer, 256);
  fgets(buffer, 255, stdin);
  n = write(sockfd, buffer, strlen(buffer));
  if( n < 0)
    error("ERROR writing to socket");

  bzero(buffer,256);
  n = read(sockfd,buffer,255);
  if (n < 0) 
    error("ERROR reading from socket");
  printf("%s\n",buffer);
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What does `bzero` do and why do you pass `file` to `bzero` in the first snippet?

Comment: it is like `memset` except it always initializes all the values to zero unlike `memset` in which you can initialize the values to anything.

Comment: So why do you zero `file` before passing it to `write`? Isn't that the reason of the behaviour you are experiencing?

Comment: @MaciejHehl Yeah your right that does make sense but I commented that out and it still didn't even work.

Comment: Umm.. your 'file' char array is only 9 bytes long, why are you zero'ing 256 bytes? That's a buffer overflow right there. What does "the program does not move forward" mean anyway? Does it just hang, or crash? What is this code even supposed to do?

Comment: @Thomas It hangs, yes I commented that line out. I am trying to write a simplified ftp protocol, so my programs connects to a public ftp server and I am trying to retrieve a file from that server after I connect to it. I know my connection works because when I write the stdin stuff to it I get a response back from the server.